# Plotting multiple variable trends over years for 3 continents (trend time series plot in ggplot)

Tags: ggplot2, plotly

> `amr <- read.csv("amr_paraB_trends.csv")`

so this table consists of 16 columns:

1. Continents (America, Asia, Europe)
2. Years (1965 1976    1981    1988    2001    2002    2003    2004    2005    2006    2007    2008    2009    2010    2011    2012    2013    2014    2015    2016    2017    2018    2019    2020    2021)
3. Streptomycin
4. Spectinomycin
5. Kanamycin
6. Ampicillin
7. Trimethoprim
8. Chloramphenicol
9. Ciprofloxacin_IR
10. Sulfisoxazole
11. Tetracycline
12. Nalidixic_acid
13. Colistin
14. Cefoxitin
15. Ceftriaxone
16. Lincomycin

    than i converted this table to long df:

> ```
> > amr$Years <- format(amr$Years, format = "%Y")
> >     library(ggplot2)
> >     library(tidyr)
> >     df_long <- pivot_longer(amr, 
> >                             cols = c(Streptomycin,  Spectinomycin,  Kanamycin,  Ampicillin, Trimethoprim,   Chloramphenicol,    Ciprofloxacin_IR,   Sulfisoxazole,  Tetracycline,   Nalidixic_acid, Colistin,   Cefoxitin,  Ceftriaxone,    Lincomycin),
> > 
> >                             values_to = "Isolates",
> >                             names_to = "Phenotypes")
> >
> ```

than I want to plot the trends of each phenotypes (Streptomycin, kanamycin and etc) over years for each continent.

> ```
> >     ##plot
> >     ggplot(df_long, aes(x = Years, y = Isolates, color = Phenotypes, linetype = Continents)) +
> >       geom_line(size = 0.7) +
> >       ggtitle("Trend of amr over years") + 
> >       xlab("Year") +
> >       ylab("No of isolates) +
> >       #x_continuous(breaks = seq(1975, 2022, by = 1)) +
> >       theme_minimal()
> ```

but this is not producing trend lines the graph is empty.

can anyone helps?

Comment: Can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) by providing your data using `dput()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you have provided so far, the two main issues are that your `ylab` axis title is lacking an apostrophe (leading to an `Error: unexpected symbol` message) and that your `x_continuous` argument should be [`scale_x_continuous`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_continuous.html); you can specify `limits`, `breaks`, and `labels` to tailor the x-axis for what you're trying to make. I also used the `lubridate` package to transform `Years`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
set.seed(123)

Continents <- sample(c("Asia", "America", "Europe"), 100, replace = T)
Years <- sample(c(1965, 1976, 1981, 1988, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021), 100, replace = T)
Streptomycin <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = T); Spectinomycin <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = T); Kanamycin <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = T)
Ampicillin <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = T); Trimethoprim <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = T); Chloramphenicol <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = T)
Ciprofloxacin_IR <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = T); Sulfisoxazole <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = T); Tetracycline <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = T)
Nalidixic_acid <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = T); Colistin <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = T); Cefoxitin <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = T)
Ceftriaxone <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = T); Lincomycin <- sample(1:100, 100, replace = T)

df <- data.frame(Continents, Years, Streptomycin, 
         Spectinomycin, Kanamycin, Ampicillin, 
         Trimethoprim, Chloramphenicol, Ciprofloxacin_IR, 
         Sulfisoxazole, Tetracycline, Nalidixic_acid, Colistin, 
         Cefoxitin, Ceftriaxone, Lincomycin)

df_long <- pivot_longer(df, cols = c(Streptomycin, Spectinomycin, 
                                     Kanamycin, Ampicillin, Trimethoprim, 
                                     Chloramphenicol,Ciprofloxacin_IR, Sulfisoxazole, 
                                     Tetracycline, Nalidixic_acid, Colistin, 
                                     Cefoxitin, Ceftriaxone, Lincomycin),
                        values_to = "Isolates",
                        names_to = "Phenotypes") %>% 
  mutate(Years = year(as.Date(as.character(Years), format = "%Y")))

ggplot(df_long, aes(x = Years, y = Isolates, color = Phenotypes, linetype = Continents)) +
  geom_line(size = 0.7) +
  ggtitle("Trend of amr over years") + 
  xlab("Year") +
  ylab("No of isolates") +
  scale_x_continuous("Years", 
                     labels = as.character(Years), 
                     limits = c(1975, 2022),
                     breaks = Years,
                     guide = guide_axis(check.overlap = T)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. But this is becoming to messy I would like to add a decade info like plots based in 10 years instead yearly . I tried to give breaks of 10 years but that not adding up values for 1 decade

Comment: If you have an additional question about formatting of the x-axis, you can post a separate question on StackOverflow (with a reproducible example).